# Events design - using events to trigger initialisation events

Tags: c#, event-handling

I have a view class that listens for a change on any cell property in a list of cells.
New cells can be added at any time. What is the best way to tell my view class to listen to the new cells that have just been added *without* the cells knowing about the view class at all.

My current method is to use another event listener to listen to changes in the list. When this happens i add the listener to its relevent properites. Is that the best way to do this?

**More info on my particular situation:**

I have used events sparingly in other projects but this is the first time i am embracing them in a big way with one master data class and many different views that show the data in different formats.

My research on good design only extends as far as having read [Head First design patterns](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Head-First-Design-Patterns-Freeman/dp/0596007124) so please do recommend any good resources on using the event pattern in a nice clean way as my project is beocming a difficult to track mess!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, what you describe is the common practice.  Listen for changes to the list then in those handlers, hook into change events on the added items.  The catch is to make sure you also *remove* those event handlers as items are dropped from the list - otherwise you will have memory leaks.

Comment: "make sure you also remove those event handlers as items are dropped from the list"...or use weak event pattern, as it implemented in WPF.